# Setting font color when the document opens isn't working

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

So I'm working on creating a document for some folks where each group, of which there are three, is assigned a font color for their input into the document.  I've written a VBA script that contains a list of everyone involved and can identify the person logged into the computer and the group they are with.  However, I am unable to get the font color to set itself.  I recorded a VBA script where I set the font color to see how Word does it, but the resulting code of `Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed` won't actually change the selected font color when I add it to my VBA script.  Here is an example of the code that I'm using:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim Users As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim UserID As String
Dim category As String

UserID = GetUserName 'Currently using the example at
                     'http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161394 as a function

'---Add Members of Group 1---
Users.Add "person1", "group1"
Users.Add "person2", "group1"

'---Add Members of Group 2---
Users.Add "person3", "group2"
Users.Add "person4", "group2"
Users.Add "person5", "group2"

'---Add Members of Group 3---
Users.Add "person6", "group3"
Users.Add "person7", "group3"

For Each user In Users.Keys
    If user = UserID Then
        If Users.Item(user) = "group1" Then
            Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        ElseIf Users.Item(user) = "group2" Then
            Selection.Font.Color = wdColorGreen
        ElseIf Users.Item(user) = "group3" Then
            Selection.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
        Else
            Selection.Font.Color = wdColorBlack
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: your problem is around `Selection` which is just the selected area on the sheet when it was last closed. How do you identify each users area? After you have identified this then you can set the font color for the relevant range

Comment: Anyone from any group can add text to any section of the document, which is why they wanted color coding for each user group.

Comment: why don't you use MS-Word revision features?

Comment: @Brad, hold on a second... one clarification- do you want it to work this way?- 1. someone opens document >> 2. you check which group he belongs to >> 3. each time this person select anything in document it changes color of selection to one designed for the group >> 4. or when adding new text it's written in color of the group. THIS IS POSSIBLE, but please confirm if I get you right.

Comment: @KazJaw. Point 4 is what OP wants. I would love to hear your input if it is possible.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, see possible solution.

Comment: I wanted it so: 1.  Person opens the document. 2.  Document_Open() macro runs, identifying the person and associated group and 3. then setting the font color for any new text that the person types into the document.

Comment: @Brad, then my solution works in this way...

Comment: @KazJaw, thanks for the info and I wish I could use it, but it seems to impede the rest of the "system".  I didn't mention the rest of the "system" as it didn't occur to me that functions specific to this document would cause issues.  Basically, the document I'm working on ties into this whole VBA ecosystem that I've spent more than a year learning and am still nowhere near done.  Basically, a bunch of values are passed to the document from this ecosystem when it first opens and the color changes outlined in your solution messes with that by coloring things that shouldn't be colored. :(

Comment: @Brad, what you have asked for was rather complicated. As I stated in edition to my answer most of inconveniences could be solved by additional `If statements`. However, you would need to spend some time to add all of `breaks to the rules` to get code running with fully satisfaction for you. Therefore back to my first suggestion- use `Revision feature` which, if used appropriate, could be that what you search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't set a default font color for a specific user. Even if you managed to, say, set it to Blue and you navigate to a sentence which is in red color and if you typed anything, you will not see blue text but red text. Because the position where the cursor is will pick the original color that was used to color that sentence.

To set a specific color for a user, you will either have to either

1. `Identify a range and set the color for it`. But then like I mentioned above, if the user navigates to a different range then the new color setting will not apply there.
2. `Set it for the entire document`. If you set it for the entire document then the color of the entire document will change and I am sure this is not what you want.

Comment: As disappointed as I am, I think you are correct that what I'm wanting to do can't be done.  I'm marking your answer as the correct one. :(

Comment: AFAIK and I could be wrong but there is no event in MS-Word which can trap text changes. Else we could have come up with a workaround.

Comment: That is kind of what annoyed me with the macro I recorded - I started the recording, typed some black text, changed text color, then typed in the new color.  The macro showed the initial text, then the `selection` line of code, then the new-colored text.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround bases on  `Application.WindowSelectionChange Event`. Therefore you need to keep the following steps:

1.Create Class module 
2.Name your Class module `App` 
3.Add the following code to `App Class Module`:

```
    Public WithEvents WRD As Application

    Private Sub WRD_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
        'here you should place solution from your Document_Open sub
        'which defines color based on user name or...
        'you could place it somewhere else but pass color value 
        'here as a parameter

        'for test I just assumed that color should be blue
        Sel.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    End Sub
```

4.In standard module add public variable:

```
    Public tmpApp As New App
```

5.Create Sub in standard module, or add code to your `Document_Open Event`, which will initialize our class:

```
Sub Document_Open_new()

    Set tmpApp.WRD = Application

    'we need to change selection once to trigger full
    'scope of solution
    'if we omit the code below new color will not work
    'if user add new text at the beginning of the document
    'right after it was opened
    Dim tmpSel As Range
    Set tmpSel = Selection.Range
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select
    tmpSel.Select
End Sub
```

6.Run the above sub once or open document if the code was added to `Document_open event`.

**---EDIT---** (after some comments from @Sid below)

There are some inconveniences of using proposed solution. However, MOST OF THEM COULD BE SOLVED by adding some `If statements` inside `WindowSelectionChange event`. Checking for position of `Sel range` parameter, text around and others allows to precisely decide whether new color should be applied or not.

Comment: The code simply colors the word where I set my cursor. Which is not what OP wants. Please see my answer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout...and obviously make new written text in color which was dedicated to appropriate user. Which means that it colors selection and new text in document.

Comment: But like I said that is not what OP wants. Let's say you wrote a sentence in red and closed the file. I then open it and just place my cursor on that line to read it and not to make any changes. The selected text turn blue which shouldn't happen. But if I tried to write something in between that sentence that that word should be blue. I hope you got what I am trying to imply?

Comment: If you just ONLY place the cursor where you want to write new text then the solution is correct. So, user should just avoid over-selection if it is not necessary. I could admit- this is not perfect solution but possible workaround. Moreover, in general, there is already `Revision feature` in place for tasks as asked in question.

Comment: Most of us (as a habit) like to keep the cursor on the line that we are currently reading. Some of us even go to the extent of highlighting the row. As I mentioned in the comments in my answer there is no `Text_Change event` else it would have been a piece of cake :)

Comment: Most of us (as a habit) like to use `Revision feature` for the problem of OP :) This is only possible workaround which could be even more expanded to avoid some problems of it.